# Counter in a DFS

Tags: graph, count, depth-first-search, directed-graph

I want to make sure that if adding a counter in a DFS algorithm, nodeCount, will count the number of nodes that a DFS tree will produce. 
I'm not looking for a pre-number or post-number. All I want to know is the number of nodes in the  DFS tree. 
Will this algorithm achieve the goal? My confusion is keeping track of a counter in a recursive function.

```
nodeCount = 0;
DFS(SCCgraphG, v)
{
    v.visited = true;
    nodeCount++;

    For v’s neighbors W’s
    {
        if(w.visited == false)
            DFS(G, w);
    }
 }
```

Comment: or you can follow the bottom up implementation where you merge the results of the subcalls using return statements, sth, like declaring a local variable in the method, assigning the value of what's returned from the subcall and then adding 1 to it

Comment: This works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work, because you verify if the node was visited before call the function and increment the counter. So it will not count the same node twice.

Here you check if a certain node was visited. If it was not, you call a function for it:

```
if(w.visited == false)
    DFS(G, w);
```

Now, you **immediately** mark this node as visited and increment the counter:

```
v.visited = true;
nodeCount++;
```

If the node is visited again, it will be 'blocked' by the previous verification, so it will not call the function for the same node twice.

The only thing you need to guarantee is that, in the first call of the function, the first node V was not already visited (but that will probably not occur)

Comment: Can you provide a reference?

Comment: I couldn't find a code with this counter. It is not so usual to count the visited nodes during the DFS (usually it is done on main with a for), but it is another implementation that works.

Comment: That is what I'm driving at - if it works, can you provide more detail on the solution?